# Can't import my own personal module after setting it up

Tags: python

I'm 100% sure that I'm missing something simple, but I just can't get it to work

My directory looks like this:

```
> Project
>> setup.py
>> Project
>>> main.py
>>> a
>>>> __ init__.py
>>>> a.py
>>> b
>>>> __ init__.py
>>>> b.py
>>> c
>>>> __ init__.py
>>>> c.py
```

Inside main.py I import other submodules using `from a.a import a` syntax. It works when I call it from this module. It doesn't work only if I import the whole installed module inside the other one.

My setup.py looks like this

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name='Project',
version='0.1',
author='x',
packages=setuptools.find_packages())
```

I install it using `pip install .` and then try importing it in the other module. After doing that, I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'`.

I did try googling quite a bit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is "a" a method in the module "a"?

Comment: It's a class, sorry.

Comment: why did you write "from a.a" ?

Comment: Package a, file named a

Comment: In order to test you issue do the following, write "from a import a" then "dir(a)" . what output do you get?

Comment: Also are they all really named "a"? I assume it's for demonstration only...

Comment: Okay, they're not 'a', they're named babController. The folder, file and class has the same name.

Comment: dir(a) prints the method list of class a when I run ```python main.py``` from projects/projects directory.

The statement isn't reached when I try to import the main.py in another module

Comment: Is __ init__.py not needed anymore in the top level module directory ?

Comment: Hmm, will test it out

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: from project.a.a import a ??

Comment: This might work, but I have to refactor the whole module AND it doesn't seem like the way it should work.

Comment: Sorry about that, Your statement : ‘Inside main.py I import other submodules using from a.a import a syntax. It works when I call it from this module. It doesn't work only if I import the whole installed module inside the other one. ‘ it’s not really clear to me

Comment: If I run 'main.py' from the 'project/project' folder, everything works smooth.

I have another module in which I want to use this 'project/project/main.py' as an import. If I import it, it tries to import the 'a' submodule, which fails.

Comment: Add a __main__.py at top level ?

Comment: packages=find_packages(include=['package_name', 'package_name.*'])